# Pointers created on stack get destroyed? (diagram included) :- )

Tags: pointers, buffer

If I create a buffer of pixels on the heap 6 by 10 ....

int *p_buffer = new int[6 * 10]

```
p_buffer---
          |
          |
          V
          * * * * * * * * * *
          * * * * * * * * * *
          * * * * * * * * * *
          * * * * * * * * * *
          * * * * * * * * * *
          * * * * * * * * * *
```

Then in a method I create 6 pointers but I don't define them as "new", I understand this means they are stored on the stack.  I create an array of pointers like so:

```
int *p_row[6];
```

Then I manually place each p_row pointer at the start of each row, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
     p_row[i] = p_buffer + (10 * i);
    }
```

So now we have:

```
 p_buffer---
           |
           |
           V
p_row[0]-->* * * * * * * * * *
p_row[1]-->* * * * * * * * * *
p_row[2]-->* * * * * * * * * *
p_row[3]-->* * * * * * * * * *
p_row[4]-->* * * * * * * * * *
p_row[5]-->* * * * * * * * * *
```

I'm wondering, if after doing this the program leaves this function and goes back to main(), whether I can do something like:

```
p_row[0] = (set my RGB colours);
```

I've learned that things created in a function (local scope) are destroyed if created on the stack (without allocating or using 'new' keyword).

After it leaves that function, are the pointers destroyed?  And can I reference them?

I know this is an unorthodox way of referencing bytes, but the question is about the mechanics of pointers.  The whole buffer is allocated through p_buffer, which I intend to delete after the program quits.  I'm sorry if the answer if obvious.

In addition, the array of pointers p_row[] will be a member of the class Screen, if this makes a difference.

Comment: You defined them as local variable, how would you use them out of the function ? That won't even compile. Of course you can't reference a local variable out of its scope.

Comment: One extra detail I added, the array of pointers p_row[] will be a member of the Screen class.

Comment: You shouldn't think about stack or whatever. Stack isn't even defined in the language. Think about scopes. If your variables are member of a class, then the scope is the class, and it stays valid as long as the class is. Think of `new`ed memory as scope-less. In `int *a = new int;`, `a` is a local pointer to a scope-less `int`.

Comment: Right, thank you.  In this case I didn't "new" it or allocate memory, so I thought anytime you didn't the variable is destroyed upon leaving the function.  But it seems that if it's a member of a class this is an exception?  By the way the class is completely static, and not instantiated, I access it like:  Screen::p_row[i].  I'm still learning about statics and singletons.  I'll mark the question as answered, thank you, but I'll leave it for a bit to see what anyone has to say or if you have anything to add.

Comment: In your case, the variable is defined in the class scope, not in any function, so it will stay valid as long as the class is valid. The class itself will be destroyed when it goes out of its own scope. If you declared the variable as static in the class, then it is special and it is never destroyed. It becomes like a global variable that is accessed with `Screen::`. As a side note, you should not use singleton, unless you really know what you are doing. If everything can work without the "static", then just remove the statics, and create one `Screen`.

Comment: Thanks so much.  If you want to add your comment as the answer, I'll pick it as answered.